# Sort strings based on the number of distinct characters

Tags: python

I am confused why the code below, which is looking to sort strings based on their number of distinct alphabets, requires the `set()` and `list()` portions.

```
strings = ['foo', 'card', 'bar', 'aaaa', 'abab']

strings.sort(key = lambda x: len(set(list(x))))
print(strings)
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't need `list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, the key of that code is the `set()` function. Why? Because it will return a set with not-repeated elements. For example:

```
set('foo') -> ['f', 'o']
set('aaaa') -> ['a']
set('abab') -> ['a', 'b']
```

Then, in order to *sort* based on the number of distinct alphabets, the `len()` function is used.

Comment: Yes, but it seems to work without the `list(...)` call in my testing. I can't think of a reason it would need it.

Comment: You're right, @PeterGibson. It doesn't need it because strings are iterable, just like lists.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question! Let's peel the layers off the `sort()` call.

According to [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) on `sort` and `sorted`,

> *key* specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element: key=str.lower. The default value is None (compare the elements directly).

That is, `sort` takes a keyword argument `key` and expects it to be a function. Specifically, it wants a `key(x)` function that will be used to generate a key value for each string in `strings` list, instead of the usual lexical ordering. In the Python shell:

```
>>> key = lambda x: len(set(list(x)))
>>> ordering = [key(x) for x in strings]
>>> ordering
[2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4]
```

This could be any ordering scheme you like. Here, we want to order by the number of *unique letters*. That's where `set` and `list` come in. `list("foo")` will result in `['f', 'o', 'o']`. Then we get `len(list('foo')) == 3` -- the length of the word. Not the number of unique characters.

```
>>> key2 = lambda x: len(list(x))
>>> ordering2 = [key2(x) for x in strings]
>>> ordering2
[3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

So we use `set` and `list` to get a set of characters. A `set` is like a `list`, except they only include the unique elements of a `list`. For instance we can make a list of characters for any word like this:

```
>>> list(strings[0])
['f', 'o', 'o']
```

And a set:

```
>>> set(list(strings[0]))
set(['o', 'f'])
```

The `len()` of that `set` is 2, so when `sort` goes to compare the "foo" in `strings[0]` to all the other `strings[x]` in `strings`, it uses this list. For example:

```
>>> (len(set(strings[0][:])) < len(set(strings[1][:])))
True
```

Which gives us the ordering we want.

EDIT: @PeterGibson pointed out above that `list(string[i])` isn't needed. This is true because strings are iterable in Python, just like lists:

```
>>> set("foo")
set(['o', 'f'])
```